# WPF , MVVM , MasterDetailPage , Designing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i'm trying to walk my way in the mvvm world,

i'm not suing any framework , only what i saw in 
http://blog.roboblob.com/tag/viewmodellocator/

i really like that post and it works very well.

i'm trying to create a master details view that containes 3 user control.
one of them need to change depending on user inputs ( like a wizard)

so i have something like

```
MasterDetailsView
 -> MenuView
 -> FirstPageView
 -> SliderView
```

by the post i read, each view create his own viewmodel and bind it "automaticly"
so FirstPageView got his viewmodel.

if SliderView change selection i want to bind to FirstPageView a new viewmodel

if FirstPageView got button (Next) click inside it i want to switch FirstPageView to SecondPageView and etc..

i'm a bit lost, anyone can please show me the way how to design and solve this ?

should i use mvvm light or some other framework ? i tryed to use mvvm light but that lack of examples holds me back.

any guidance will be welcome, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement below is wrong:

> each view create his own viewmodel and bind it "automaticly" so
>   FirstPageView got his viewmodel

Your views should not be responsible for the lifecycle of your view model.

One of the most important things to remember when using the MVVM pattern is that it should be possible to execute your application without your view. In your case in would create a view model that closely mirrors your desired view. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
MasterDetailsViewModel
{
  MenuViewModel
  CurrentPageViewModel
  SliderViewModel
}
```

Notice the big difference here is that we have a CurrentPageViewModel, not a view model that is specific to a page. This property starts off as a FirstPageViewModel instance, then changes as the users advances from one page to the next.

For details on how to achieve this, I would thoroughly recommend the article by Josh Smith:

[WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: thanks, i will read this, one question, how can i keep the view blandability your way?

Comment: MVVM promotes Blendability, although you might need to add design-time data. If my answer helped, please upvote or mark as answer.

Comment: thanks, but im not sure how to add design time data, can u show me how please?